# PowerPC Assembly: How to pass and return multiple arguments?

Tags: assembly, subroutine, powerpc

I am learning PPC Assembly but am having a hard time understanding the following about sub routine calls:

What registers can be used to pass arguments to a sub routine? I think it is R3 to R12?
How do you pass arguments when you run out of registers? Could I please see a code example of this.

When passing back return values, can you only use R3? From what I understand you can only use this register to return a single value. If you need to return more values then you return a pointer to those values? Could I possibly see a code example for this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're writing in assembly language, you can do whatever you want.  It's only when you want to interact with some external code (maybe a library, maybe a system call) that you need to obey the calling convention.  Some architectures have multiple different ABIs, so you have to be careful.

If I recall correctly, pretty much everybody uses the same calling convention for 32-bit PowerPC, so [this Apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/100-32-bit_PowerPC_Function_Calling_Conventions/32bitPowerPC.html) should have everything you need to know.  As you mention, parameters are commonly passed in R3-R10 and the return value is put in R3.  [This tutorial](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~mburrel/stuff/ppc-asm.html) seems to indicate the same.